# Xamarin forms error LoadApplication(new App());

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I just created a new cross-platform project and run the app without writing any code or change any configuration and i got the following error:

Unhandled Exception:

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool:_freeRenderers' (0) due to: Could not resolve type with token 0100027b from typeref (expected class 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1' in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e') assembly:mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e type:System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1 member:(null) occurred

I tired to update Nuget packages, remove bin and obj then rebuild. still error occurs.

Comment: you need VS2019 or downgrade the Xamarin.Forms version

Comment: @Saad, Please don't use latest Xamarin.forms version, try to use 4.3.0.778476-pre1 version and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is tracked [on the Xamarin Forms Github Issues page](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7602) and seems to be quite common. The solution seems to be to make sure that you have the latest version of Visual Studio installed. Let me know if that doesn't work.